Magento 2 : Invoice PDF Need Product Detail Customization
How can I add table structure to product section of the Invoice Pdf in Magento Invoice PDF?

Depends on what you're trying to do (?)
look at this for inspiration : vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php::_drawHeader()

Check is this extension helpfull to you or not : https://magecomp.com/magento-2-download-invoice-pdf.html
